# Get Runtime error '429' ActiveX component can't create object when Macro run with Task Scheduler

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have this VBA code use to send emails in my Access Database, and I also Referenced the Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library.

Everything works perfectly when I run the code manually. However, Access fails when I run the Macro from Windows Task Schedular. I get this message:

Runtime error '429' ActiveX component can't create object

In the Actions tab in Task Scheduler I am referencing the Macro like this:
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE" "C:\mydata\Database\mydatabase.accdb" /X RunMyMacro

The error seem to be pointing to this code as indicated in the screenshot below.

***Code:***

```
Dim strEmailBody As String

Sub emailNotification()
Dim oFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim oItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim oOutlook As New Outlook.Application

Dim MoOutlook As Outlook.NameSpace
Set MoOutlook = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oFolder = MoOutlook.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderOutbox)
Set oItem = oFolder.Items.Add(olMailItem)
With oItem
.Recipients.Add ("tome@me.com")
.Subject = "my notification"
.Body = strEmailBody
.Importance = olImportanceHigh
.Send
End With
Set oFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```

***Screenshot:***

[image]

Comment: can you run `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE" "C:\mydata\Database\mydatabase.accdb" /X RunMyMacro` in the command line?

Comment: Yes it works when I type or paste the above in the command line. Is this a problem with Task Scheduler?

Comment: have you tried editing the permissions?  http://superuser.com/questions/402070/run-task-scheduler-task-on-demand-from-limited-user-account-in-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code in a batch file and run the batch file from Windows Scheduler.

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE" "C:\mydata\Database\mydatabase.accdb" /X RunMyMacro
```

Comment: Actually I just tried that and got the same error. This just stinks.

Comment: Yes, when I open the bat file, it opens Access and runs the Macro successfully. When I type the bat location in Command it also runs the macro successfully. But Failed on Task Scheduling.

Comment: I have isolated the problem to the email part of the code, I simply commented out the entire email code and it works fine. I think I am going to contact the author of the book who wrote the script.

Comment: Good work, I hope you can get this resolved.  As a last resort you could always go with something like Total Access Emailer http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Emails.asp

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20584/discussion-between-unaverage-guy-and-hellow)